# Get a tag assigned to custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using `WooCommerce` and have tagged one of `products` (custom post type is `product`) with the tag "electronic".

I'm now trying to loop through and obtain the tag assigned to that post, but currently, when trying to dump the data, I'm returned with `bool(false)`.

Here is my approach:

```html
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'p' => $product_name,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ($loop->have_posts()):
    $loop->the_post();

    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags)
    {
        foreach ($posttags as $tag)
        {
            echo $tag->name;
        }
    }

    var_dump($posttags);

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'p' => $product_name,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ($loop->have_posts()):
    $loop->the_post();

    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags)
    {
        foreach ($posttags as $tag)
        {
            echo $tag->name;
        }
    }

    var_dump($posttags);

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Have tried:

```html
<?php
global $post;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'p' => $product_name,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

$product_tags = get_the_terms($post, 'product_tag');

while ($loop->have_posts()):
    $loop->the_post();

    if ($product_tags){
        foreach ($product_tags as $tag){
            echo $tag->name;
        }
    }

endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But the above doesn't echo anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `get_the_tags()` is used only for post tags, not WooCommerce's product tags. For WooCommerce, the taxonomy should be `product_tag`. You may use

```
<?php
$product_tags = get_the_terms( $post, 'product_tag' );
?>
```

to get the tags and then loop over them as required.

Full code example:

```
<?php
global $post;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'p' => $product_name,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ($loop->have_posts()):
    $loop->the_post();

    $product_tags = get_the_terms($post, 'product_tag');

    if ($product_tags && !is_wp_error($product_tags){
        foreach ($product_tags as $tag){
            echo $tag->name;
        }
    }

endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tried your approach, may just be me implementing it incorrectly, but it doesn't echo anything for me still. I've edited my question to showcase my approach

Comment: Hi, please try putting `get_the_terms()` inside the loop. This is because in your case, `$post` object is available only within the loop. (My answer has been edited to reflect the full code)